# What is a meaningful signifcance level when considering a pre-test and post-test model to assess learning in a college course?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

When using a pre-test/post-test assessment to measure college learning, what is a meaningful significance level?  I realize that p<.05 is the minimum criterion, yet with a correlated-groups t-test, it doesn't take much improvement to achieve this significance level.  I'm getting p<.0001 by achieving only a moderate overall increase in scores with N=35.

Comment: Significance levels are always arbitrary and are determined differently by convention or tradition in each field.  Given your value of p<0.0001 with an N of only 35, your effect seems intuitively unlikely to be due to chance (given a vague assumption that variability within individuals is generally speaking fairly low), so you should calculate effect size to see if the effect is big enough to care about.